# codeigniter 4 running error first time with xampp

Tags: php

```
Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function CodeIgniter\locale_set_default() 
in C:\xampp\htdocs\sunpay-ci4\system\CodeIgniter.php:184 
Stack trace: 
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\sunpay-ci4\system\bootstrap.php(181): CodeIgniter\CodeIgniter->initialize() 
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\sunpay-ci4\public\index.php(36): require('C:\\xampp\\htdocs...') 
#2 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\sunpay-ci4\system\CodeIgniter.php on line 184
```

I don't understand this error, the first page works if I drop this package.

Comment: Hi, please add your code, from which the error is causing with more details. Cheers.

Comment: no code ,just first add in xampp folder then get this error

Answer (score 21):

Try opening **php.ini** from the control panel:
**Apache** row -> **Config** -> **php.ini**

Then enable intl extension by removing `;` in front of `extension=intl`

Edit: the reason it fails is because the intl extension is disabled by default in xampp

Answer (score 9):

Recently I stuck on the same problem on CI version 4.0.4.

Follow the steps to fix it.

1. Click on "config" from the xampp control panel.

[image]

2. Then click on php.ini option.

[image]

3. Then it will open on your default text editor application (for me it is Notepad). then click on find option.

[image]

4. Then search for "`;extension=intl`".

[image]

5. replace "`;extension=intl`" with "`extension=intl`".

That's all. Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

1. get your php version by put this code : `phpinfo();die();` in your index.php after `<?php` so it looks like like `<?php phpinfo();die();`

**PHP Version 7.2.24-0ubuntu0.18.04.7**

2. jump to `/etc/php/{your php version}/apache2` folder; example : `/etc/php/7.2/apache2` and open php.ini then find `;extension=intl` and remove the semicolon `;`
3. open your terminal then write or copy paste this command `sudo systemctl restart apache2` and press ENTER
4. open your CI 4 again in your browser.

Welcome to CodeIgniter 4.0.4
The small framework with powerful features

==============================================================================
if you still get the same error please try to install intl extension using this command in your terminal:

```
sudo apt install php{your php version}-intl
sudo systemctl restart apache2`
```

example :

```
sudo apt install php7.2-intl
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

open your CI 4 again in your browser.

Welcome to CodeIgniter 4.0.4
The small framework with powerful features

=============================================================================

#NB :
dont forget to remove phpinfo();die(); in the first step
sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 4):

Just go to the mentioned line in display in error.
`C:\xampp\htdocs\sunpay-ci4\system\CodeIgniter.php:184`

You can find it here: `root folder/system/CodeIgniter.php`

on line no 184 you will find the below code.

```
locale_set_default($this->config->defaultLocale ?? 'en');
```

just comment it like this.

```
#locale_set_default($this->config->defaultLocale ?? 'en');
```

Now, the code is working.

Answer (score 2):

1.search for `intl` and uncomment this extension in `php.ini` file by removing `;` from begin of line `extension=intl`
2. restart Apache service by stop and starting it again from xampp control panel

Answer (score 0):

When i started a new project i got this error on welcome screen. Fatal error: Uncaught Error: //pp\Views\welcome_message.php:222 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in. It appears like there is a problem with the installation of codeigniter but in fact it is an echo error in line 222 of the welcom_message.php page go there an remove the  `<?= CodeIgniter\CodeIgniter::CI_VERSION ?>` from line 222 it should look like this

```
 <div class="heroe">

        <h1>Welcome to CodeIgniter </h1>

        <h2>The small framework with powerful features</h2>

    </div>
```

Then it will echo hello screen correctly

Answer (score 0):

Usually to get round this try these three points:

1. Ensure .writable folder is writable with file permissions 0777 (must have leading zero)
2. Try setting the following in index.php -> $_SERVER['CI_ENVIRONMENT'] = 'development'; and toggle with $_SERVER['CI_ENVIRONMENT'] = 'production' in .env file;
3. Access this file(CodeIgniter.php) in the following directory: project_folder/vendor/codeigniter4/framework/system/CodeIgniter.php

   public function initialize()
   {
   if( function_exists('locale_set_default' )):
   locale_set_default($this->config->defaultLocale ?? 'en');
   endif;}

Answer (score -1):

if your have installed Apache, PHP, MYSQL manually, then set locale to app in .env file:

```
app.locale = "en"
```

save and restart apache service