# I am trying to install codeignator4 first time on xampp sever but showing me error

Tags: php, xampp, codeigniter-4

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function CodeIgniter\locale_set_default() in C:\xampp\htdocs\codeignetor\system\CodeIgniter.php:184 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\codeignetor\system\bootstrap.php(181): CodeIgniter\CodeIgniter->initialize() #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\codeignetor\public\index.php(36): require('C:\xampp\htdocs...') #2 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\codeignetor\system\CodeIgniter.php on line 184

I also have replaced ";extention=int1" to extention=int1 in the php.init file but still, get the error please help me with it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [codeigniter 4 running error first time with xampp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62968301/codeigniter-4-running-error-first-time-with-xampp)

Comment: is this for language localization?